# ListView custom adapter iterates more times of the number of items in the list

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

From days I'm trying to figure out why my Custom Adapter is iterating more than it should. I'm trying to show 3 items, but my Custom Adapter enters the function `getView()` many times than expected.

I print a `log` each time I enter getView() and the logcat shows me this:

```
    log-entered getView 
    log-entered getView 
    log-entered getView 

    log-entered getView 
    log-entered getView 
    log-entered getView 

    .
    .
    .
    so on..
```

This happens 5 times and every time getView() comes 3 times.

The code of my **Main Activity**:

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        setContentView(R.layout.activity_torneos);

        final ListView listTorneos=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewTorneos);

        ArrayList<Torneo> list = getListData();
        listTorneos.setAdapter(new CustomListAdapter(this,list));
    }

private ArrayList<Torneo> getListData() {
        ArrayList<Torneo> results = new ArrayList<Torneo>();
        Torneo torneo = new Torneo();
        torneo.setNombre("Timiza");
        torneo.setLugar("Parque metropolitano timiza1");
        torneo.setCiudad("Bogota");
        results.add(torneo);

        torneo = new Torneo();
        torneo.setNombre("salitre");
        torneo.setLugar("Parque metropolitano timiza2");
        torneo.setCiudad("Bogota");
        results.add(torneo);

        torneo = new Torneo();
        torneo.setNombre("laverdieri");
        torneo.setLugar("Parque metropolitano timiza3");
        torneo.setCiudad("Bogota");
        results.add(torneo);


        return results;
    }
```

And the code of my *CustomAdapter class*:

```
public class CustomListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private ArrayList<NewsItem> listData;

    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

    public CustomListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<NewsItem> listData) {
        this.listData = listData;
        layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return listData.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return listData.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        Log.d("info","log-entered getView");
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row_layout, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.headlineView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
            holder.reporterNameView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.reporter);
            holder.reportedDateView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.date);
            holder.imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.thumbImage);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        NewsItem newsItem = (NewsItem) listData.get(position);

        holder.headlineView.setText(newsItem.getHeadline());
        holder.reporterNameView.setText("By, " + newsItem.getReporterName());
        holder.reportedDateView.setText(newsItem.getDate());

        if (holder.imageView != null) {
            new ImageDownloaderTask(holder.imageView).execute(newsItem.getUrl());
        }

        return convertView;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView headlineView;
        TextView reporterNameView;
        TextView reportedDateView;
        ImageView imageView;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

getView can be called multiple times per layout pass (to onMeasure and onLayout each child). You're recycling views and using a View Holder (techniques to avoid performance issues), so what is the problem?

Comment: the problem is that GetView method downloaded an image for each item of the list, and the method GetView in my code is called 15 times, 5 for each item, then the images are downloaded from the server 15 times,  and often images may not get the corresponding item.  THANKS

Comment: Then there is a lot of stuff to improve with your ImageDownloaderTask; caching, handling view recycling, spawning unique requests, etc. You could look at using something like http://square.github.io/picasso/ or https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader